# Does Superman ever go sunbathing?

Tags: dc, superman

As I'm sure we all know by now, Superman gets his powers by being exposed to our sun, a yellow star. He also gains new abilities or has them drained whilst exposed to certain different colours of star.

My question is, is there ever an instance, in any canon universe, in which Superman has gone sunbathing to either recharge his powers or as some form of training?

Comment: Does this count? http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-v0drI-G1r9c/UqPeeypF7UI/AAAAAAAA5B0/bs5z5ewl9Oo/s1600/splash-supermanmanoftomorrow-13.jpg

Comment: After nearly dying, Superman takes a breather to recharge his batteries at his Fortress of Solitude; http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-vNYpWMlITgY/US7BjMrj56I/AAAAAAAAJWg/SOo6Fp5ERMY/s640/vlcsnap-2013-02-28-10h04m29s49.png in Superman: Doomsday.

Comment: Superman grilling and chillin' at the beach; https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/53/e3/8c/53e38c2253ca76d22cbc82ab96ddd163.jpg

Comment: Funny thing is, our sun is not actually yellow in the slightest.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I live in England. For us, the sun is merely there to illuminate the cloud cover.

Comment: It may as well be a sheet of moderately dark grey XD

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, well, it may look yellow depending on some circumstances: http://askanastronomer.org/stars/faq/2015/11/06/is-the-sun-yellow-or-white/

Comment: @Valorum: I hear you fam

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez: Sure, for the same reason that it looks blue if you put the right filter in front of your sunglasses ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, yes, but the sky is a filter that is not easily removed.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez: Mega Maid begs to differ! ;)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes. In "[Whom the Gods Destroy #1](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman/Wonder_Woman:_Whom_Gods_Destroy_Vol_1_1)" we see Superman sunbathing. On the Moon, obviously. Because he's Superman.

[image]

Comment: That is fantastic XD

Comment: hmmmmmm the sun glasses bbecause it looks cool?

Comment: The flipflops are a nice touch.

Comment: Superman Prime flew into the sun and stayed there for 15000 years (that's right 15 millenia). At the end of this time, now-golden Superman "dwarf[ed] the might of even the massively powerful Kal Kent, who is himself more powerful than the gravitational pull of a collapsing star and faster than the speed of light." Not sure if this counts.

http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Kal-El_(DC_One_Million)

Comment: @Jack: And people say the movies are getting ridiculous

Comment: @Jack - There are tons of times when Superman has hung around near the sun getting charged up. I think we need to stick to times when he's bona fide *sunbathing* (e.g. sun lounger, trashy novel to read, etc).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - There is no plotline so dumb that the comic haven't surpassed it; http://screenrant.com/superman-comics-most-wtf-moments-ever-all-time/?view=all

Comment: So the Earth must be well behind the sun to get that nearly-full-phase illumination, meaning that Superman has moved the sun between the Earth and the moon. That's well within the Roche Limit for the Earth+sun so the planet is about to distintegrate but, hey! nice tan fella...

Comment: On the frickin' *moon* and he still wears shorts. God, what a prude!

Comment: This is very inefficient sunbathing if the sun is near the horizon.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez Less so on the moon - No athmosphere to absorb the light.  Also note the fairly short shadows.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez - He's been out there for a while. I assume it was higher earlier.

Comment: Is it less efficient _at all_ on the moon?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - In a word, [yes](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/LADEE/news/lunar-atmosphere.html#.V-vOcfkrLcc)

Comment: @Valorum: Gah I knew somebody would go there. Add "non-negligibly". A surface boundary exosphere almost might as well not exist...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Here's a question. Superman can fly. What's the rover for?

Comment: @Valorum: What's the flag for? I think he landed at a heritage site. Y'know, so that we _know_ it's the moon :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Because he's claimed that spot. If he was German, he'd have laid a towel down.

Comment: @Valorum: I'm sure I can see the torn remains of a towel at the head of the lounger ^_^ Perhaps this is why he's sunbathing on the moon... he's secretly a German and this is the only place he can truly be himself? The whole thing is actually just a Nietzschean fable...