# What comic has underground construction workers discover the Batcave (or Superman's fortress)?

Tags: story-identification, comics

I read a comic or graphic novel about a year ago in a bookshop, and vaguely remember the following events in it:

1. Construction workers extending a sewer system or something underground experience some problems and call their boss.
2. They explain to the boss that while digging they came across a wall that's built like a vault with a steel frame and x feet thick concrete etc.
3. The boss tells them to keep going (I think).
4. It is the Batcave on the other side... or if I'm truly mistaken, Superman's Fortress of Solitude.

I don't remember the year of publication though.

Which comic is this?

Comment: Fortress of Solitude is generally in the arctic so it's probably the Batcave.

Comment: The S4E7 episode of "The Batman" had a team of future archaeologists uncover the batcave in their quest to find a way to stop Mr. Freeze. But they were looking for it specifically.

Comment: “I don't remember the year of publication though.” — do you remember roughly when you read it?

Comment: @Paulie_D - his "Fortress of Solitude" has also been located in the Andes, the deep amazon and [on the moon](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/141630/does-superman-ever-go-sunbathing)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite  About an year ago. I remember reading it while browsing at a B&N.

Comment: Actually, the B&N thing brought back some more memories. Did something like that happen in a batman/superman vs predator/alien? Perhaps they don't discover bat cave but a part of batcave where batman had imprisoned a predator! Still all a vague memory.

Comment: @Valorum Yes, that;s why I said "*generally"*. All unlikely places for a subway. :)

Answer (score 7):

I have no idea if this is what you're looking for, but your description reminded me a little.  I have no context, though, I just saw the image [here](http://www.superdickery.com/the-day-superman-betrayed-batman/) and I've no clue what story is actually going on in the issue.  Maybe it will be useful in your search, or maybe just amusing?  Anyway, I hope you find what you're looking for :)

[image: http://www.superdickery.com/the-day-superman-betrayed-batman/]

Comment: It wasn't the real Batcave though, nor was Superman actually betraying Batman. The whole thing was a put-up job designed to catch a gangland boss; https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvOnz.png

Comment: @Valorum - interesting, thanks for letting me know... then it perhaps isn't a good match after all.  I don't really follow comics, so I didn't know the story behind it, as I mentioned - I simply happened to remember seeing that particular picture and wondered if it might be relevant, since the visual elements are similar.  Ah, well, perhaps someone with more comics knowledge will recall the story OP is looking for.

Comment: It's close enough that it's worth a mention. You have my +1, if for no other reason than that I had an excuse to re-read this rather amusing story.